# Debugging flows seems really painful

Tags: corda

I'm running into serious productivity issues when debugging flows. I can only assume at this point is due to a lack of knowledge on my part; particularly effective debugging techniques of flows. The problems arise when I have one flow which needs to "wait" for a consumption of a specific state. What seems to happen is the waiting flow starts and waits for the consumption of the specified state, but despite implemented as a listening future with an associated call back (at this point I'm simply using getOrThrow on the future returned from 'WhenConsumed'), the flows just hang and I see hundreds of Artemis send/write messages in the console window. If I stop the debug session, delete the node build directory, redeploy the nodes and start again the flows restart and I can return to the point of failure. However if I simply stop and detach the debugger from the node and attempt to run the calling test (calling the flow via RPC), nothing seems to happen. It's almost as if the flow code (probably incorrect at this point) results in the StateMachine/messaging layer becoming stuck in some kind of stateful loop which is only resolved by wiping the node build directories and redeploying. Simply restarting the node results in the flow no longer executing at all. This is a real productivity killer, and so I'm writing this question in the hope and assumption I've missed an obvious trick in how to effectively test/debug flows in such a way which avoids repeatedly re-deploying the nodes.
It would be great if someone could explain how to effectively debug flows; especially flows which are dependent on vault updates and thus wait on a valut update event. I have considered using a subflow, but this would ultimately, (I believe?) not result in quite the functionality required; namely to have a flow triggered when an identified state is consumed by a node. Or maybe it would? Perhaps this issue is due to not using a subFlow??? I look forward to your thoughts anyway!!

Comment: R3's Slack would be a better place for a discussion. The format here is question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your specific use case.  But in general,
I would do as much unit testing as possible before physically running the nodes and see if the flow works. 
Corda provides three levels of unit testing: transaction/ledger DSL, mock network and driver DSL. So if done right, most if not all bugs in the flows should be resolved by the time of runnodes. Actual runnodes mostly just reveal configuration issues.

Comment: See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/tree/release-V1/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example for some examples of contract and flow tests.

Comment: Thanks both. As it happens I had started to look at the testing DSL, but I had some (probably false) doubts I would be able to test all aspects of my flows in this manner. Your comments provide a degree of assurance so I will spent some using the the mock network and driver DSL. Many thanks.

Comment: I tried the DSL testing and realised the answers don't relate to my actual question; apologies this wasn't a question about "how to test Corda". It was specifically how to avoid nodes hanging after Artemis errors resulting from rpc disconnects. The nodes often do not appear to recover resiliently from an exception during a debug session which then results in having to manually shut down the nodes and restart them; typically I see many Artemis errors in the console window and at this point the node is effectively incommunicado.  Will post a detailed question on this in due cause with log files.